# I am setting seed on Gradient Boosting Machine(GBM) Model but I keep on getting different prediction

Tags: r, gbm

I am performing credit risk modelling using the Gradient Boosting Machine (GBM) algorithm and on making predictions of Probability of Default (PD) I keep on getting different PDs for each run even when I have `set.seed(1234)` in my code.

What could be causing this to happen and how do I fix it. Here is my code below:

```
fitControl <- trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 5,
  repeats = 5)

modelLookup(model='gbm')

#Creating grid
grid <- expand.grid(n.trees=c(10,20,50,100,500,1000),shrinkage=c(0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5),n.minobsinnode
                    = c(3,5,10),interaction.depth=c(1,5,10))

#SetSeed
set.seed(1234)


# training the model
model_gbm<-train(trainSet[,predictors],trainSet[,outcomeName],method='gbm',trControl=fitControl,tuneGrid=grid)
# summarizing the model
print(model_gbm)

plot(model_gbm)

#using tune length
model_gbm<-train(trainSet[,predictors],trainSet[,outcomeName],method='gbm',trControl=fitControl,tuneLength=10)

print(model_gbm)

plot(model_gbm)

#Checking variable importance for GBM
#Variable Importance
library(gbm)
varImp(object=model_gbm, numTrees = 50)

#Plotting Varianle importance for GBM
plot(varImp(object=model_gbm),main="GBM - Variable Importance")

#Checking variable importance for RF
varImp(object=model_rf)

#Plotting Varianle importance for Random Forest
plot(varImp(object=model_rf),main="RF - Variable Importance")

#Checking variable importance for NNET
varImp(object=model_nnet)

#Plotting Variable importance for Neural Network
plot(varImp(object=model_nnet),main="NNET - Variable Importance")

#Checking variable importance for GLM
varImp(object=model_glm)

#Plotting Variable importance for GLM
plot(varImp(object=model_glm),main="GLM - Variable Importance")

#Predictions
predictions<-predict.train(object=model_gbm,testSet[,predictors],type="raw")
table(predictions)

confusionMatrix(predictions,testSet[,outcomeName])

PD <- predict.train(object=model_gbm,credit_transformed[,predictors],type="prob")
```

Comment: Hi! Try to keep your example minimal, remove all non-relevant part, focus on your problem and make it reproducible (we should be able to copy/paste your example and run it on our part an see, as you said, different predictions at each run).

Comment: This will give your answer more attention. You can use fake data, some classic (available in baseR) datasets (`mtcars`,`iris`), or `dput()` a small portion of your data to build your example.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `train()` from `caret`.
I recommend you use the more complex but customizable `trainControl()` from the same package.
As you can see from `?trainControl`, the parameter `seeds` is:

> an optional set of integers that will be used to set the seed at each
>   resampling iteration. This is useful when the models are run in
>   parallel. A value of NA will stop the seed from being set within the
>   worker processes while a value of NULL will set the seeds using a
>   random set of integers. Alternatively, a list can be used. The list
>   should have B+1 elements where B is the number of resamples, unless
>   method is "boot632" in which case B is the number of resamples plus 1.
>   The first B elements of the list should be vectors of integers of
>   length M where M is the number of models being evaluated. The last
>   element of the list only needs to be a single integer (for the final
>   model). See the Examples section below and the Details section.

Fixing `seeds` should do the trick. 
Please, next time try to offer a `dput` o analogous of your data in order to be reproducible.
Best!

Comment: Alternatively, set `allowParallel = FALSE`.